# How to calculate a weighted final grade that is not out of $100\%$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I took a professor that graded his class based on weights and not points but the class weight percentages only added up to $70\%$ not $100\%$. Below is my grades:

Quiz $10\%$ weight $\dfrac{374}{384} = 97.4\%$

HW $5\%$ weight $\dfrac{95}{199} = 47.74\%$

Test $15\%$ weight $\dfrac{144}{240} = 60\%$

Final $25\%$ weight $\dfrac{120}{200} = 60\%$

Project $10\%$ weight $\dfrac{80}{80} = 100\%$

Attendance $5\%$ weight $\dfrac{120}{120} = 100\%$

When I calculated this it amounted to a $73.04\%$ as a final grade. Is this correct or is my math assuming it was weighted out of $100\%$? If I am wrong what is my correct final? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I also get $73.04$%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your math is assuming the grades out of $100\%$.

For example, Quiz $10\%$ weight $\frac{374}{384}=68.17\%\not=97.4\%$. You have done your calculation for percentage as $\frac{374}{384}$ x $100$, whereas, it's supposed to be multiplied by $70$.

Similarly for all the others.